# How to find the maximum value among a range of count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, max

it is the first time that I ask a question about stackoverflow and I have recently used MySQL.
**I need a query that allows me to find the one with the largest value from a range of counts.**
I will give you an example showing a "pseudo code" obviously not working:

```
/* function TicketCount(:time){ */
SELECT COUNT(`idT`)
FROM `TICKET`
WHERE `startTime`<=(TIME(':time')+INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND `startTime`>(TIME(':time')-INTERVAL 35 MINUTE);
/* } */

SELECT MAX( /* TicketCount( from (TIME(':time')-INTERVAL 35 MINUTE) to (TIME(':time')+INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) ) */ );
```

---

To give you an example, my table, at the moment, is this:

```
+-----+-----------+
| idT | startTime |
+-----+-----------+
|  10 | 13:00:00  |
|   9 | 12:30:00  |
|   8 | 12:30:00  |
|   7 | 11:50:00  |
|   6 | 11:30:00  |
|  11 | 13:00:00  |
+-----+-----------+
```

If ":val" were '13:00:00', the result must be '4'.
If ":val" were '11:00:00', the result must be '2'.
If ":val" were '13:35:00', the result must be '0'.

---

I hope it has made me understand and I hope there is a solution that does not consult other programming languages...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *If ":val" were '...', the result must be '...'* Why? Explain each line. *an example showing a "pseudo code"* It does not describe the grouping which is used for counting.

Comment: What's the query that produces ALL the counts.

Comment: @Akina
If ":val" were '13:00:00', the result must be '4'. This is because the maximum value of "TICKET" existing between a time band that goes from 12:25:00 (not included) to 13:10:00 (included) is, in fact, "4"... I don't know how to explain it to you in other ways...

Comment: @Strawberry ` SELECT COUNT(`idT`) FROM `TICKET` WHERE `startTime`<=(TIME(':time')+INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND `startTime`>(TIME(':time')-INTERVAL 35 MINUTE); ` This produces a COUNT from a ": val" ...

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(startTime BETWEEN ADDTIME(@time, '-00:35:00') AND ADDTIME(@time, '00:10:00'))
FROM ticket;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf53c5c82925f4622946500ee4593c10)

Comment: _**THANK YOU VERY MUCH!**_ Just one question: Shouldn't he add up the hours like this? In a nutshell, isn't it that you can give me an explanation of the code?

Comment: @ZELA *Shouldn't he add up the hours like this?* [ADDTIME() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime). *isn't it that you can give me an explanation of the code?* The condition in parenthesis tests each separate row against giving `1` when TRUe and `0` when FALSE. `SUM()` - summarized these results.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following, but note that this doesn't account for ties...

```
SELECT :val1
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM TICKET 
 WHERE startTime <= (TIME(':val')+INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
   AND startTime >  (TIME(':val')-INTERVAL 35 MINUTE)
 UNION
SELECT :val2
     , COUNT(*)  
  FROM TICKET 
 WHERE startTime <= (TIME(':val')+INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
   AND startTime >  (TIME(':val')-INTERVAL 35 MINUTE)
SELECT :val3
     , COUNT(*)  
  FROM TICKET 
 WHERE startTime <= (TIME(':val')+INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
   AND startTime >  (TIME(':val')-INTERVAL 35 MINUTE)
 ORDER  
    BY total DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
```